# Are there any good resources for dealing with "User Document" (.dob) files

Tags: vb6, activex, activex-documents

I've inherited a vb6 application that makes use of "Visual Basic User Document" files (.dob).

This tech seems to be abandoned and forgotten.

Are there any good resources out there for working with them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost no-one used ActiveX Documents when they first came out, and I imagine there's hardly anyone using them now. I've never used them. Here's some suggestions. I haven't read the ActiveX Document sections myself (never needed to) but I know they are reliable sources of information on Visual Basic and ActiveX.

- The [programmer's guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa240787(VS.60).aspx) always explains the basics very well. Try the [ActiveX document section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa240787(VS.60).aspx).
- Dan Appleman's excellent book [Developing COM/ActiveX components with Visual Basic 6](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1562765760) has a couple of chapters on ActiveX documents. You can usually [pick it up second hand](http://www.abebooks.co.uk/servlet/SearchResults?an=dan+appleman&kn=activex+visual+basic+6&sortby=3&sts=t&x=54&y=4) very cheaply.

Comment: Yah, I know. But someone used tech because it was there. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't worked with them myself but here are a couple of pages that talk about VB ActiveX User Documents:

- [ActiveX Documents in Visual Basic](http://www.aivosto.com/visdev/vdmbvis58.html)
- [The Visual Basic IDE as an ActiveX Document Container](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa241638%28VS.60%29.aspx)